# keycloak: Determine which RequiredAction was initially called in info.ftl

Tags: keycloak

I am using custom required actions in keycloak 16. Now at the end of the action processing the user sees the content of the info.ftl template. Is it possible to use different info.ftls depending on which action was performed or is there a way to find out which action(s) where executed from within the info.ftl template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped myself by adding a cookie in the request an query this cookie in the info.ftl. Not very elegant, but it works for me.